# Retry for three times If the File Exists in c# through Recursive Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Could anyone help me out by providing the solution through Recursive Methods

My Requirement is I want a recursive method, that needs to run the below code three times:

Below is my C# Working Code :

```
public void Process()
 {
     bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");

     for(int i = 0; i < 3 && exists; i++)
     {    
         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
         Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing
         exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");             
     }
     Console.WriteLine(exists);
     Console.ReadLine();

 }
```

Comment: Can you clear up your question a bit, and I will try and help you. Do you want a recursive method, that needs to run the above code three times?  Or do you want a recursive method, that if the file does not exist anymore, do not continue uninstalling?

Comment: Hi Monstertjie_za , I Want A Recursive Method that needs to run the above code three times .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code, with the for loop, does exactly what your recursive function will do. I am not too happy with posting this code.  The only valid time I could think of using a recursive function, is when you are building up a Tree structure of some sorts.

You should also be aware, if you do not implement a recursive function properly, and you do not break the continuous loop you might create using recursive functions, you will run into an `StackOverflow` exception, due to your method being called is added to the stack, and the stack will eventually run out of memory.

Here is one way of implementing a recursive function for your needs:

```
public void Process(int count = 0)
    {
        bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");

        if (exists && count < 3)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing

            //File exists
            Console.WriteLine("File exists");

            Process(++count);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exceeded retry of 3 times. File did not uninstall.");
        }

        if (!exists)
            Console.WriteLine("File uninstalled");

    }
```

Comment: Working ! Thanks A Lottt :) But i want to return bool in this code would you help me ???

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet for Recursive Method. Try it and let me know if you have any queries.

```
static bool FileExists(bool _fileexists, int Count)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Inside File Check");
        Count++;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return (_fileexists == false && Count <=3) ? FileExists(File.Exists("C:\\IFRToolLog1.txt"),Count) : true;            
    }
```

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar , But the Above code doesn't retry Right ? it only return true (or) false

Comment: It will retry until the True condition is met.

Comment: How do we need to call this in page load ???                                   public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            FileExists(bool fileexists);
            //Boolean fileexists1;
            //Program.FileExists(fileexists1);
        }

Comment: Just Call FileExists(false).

Comment: One Last Help Raj Kumar it's working fine but can we return to bool in the below post which monstertjie_za posted ?? I couldn't copy the code and paste in the comment

Comment: Actually i wanted to show the count in that way and return to bool

Comment: And one more thing is when i execute the code if the file does not exists then it is retrying infinite times i only want it to retry for 3 times if the file exists

Comment: public void Process(int count = 0) {
bool exists = File.Exists("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\RevisionNumber.txt");
 if (exists && count < 3)
{            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\sk185462\\Desktop\\SVNUPDATED\\SvnUninstallation.exe");
Thread.Sleep(2000); // or long enough to ensure the uninstall process finishes executing
//File exists
Console.WriteLine("File exists");
Process(++count);
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine("Exceeded retry of 3 times. File did not uninstall.");
}
if (!exists)
Console.WriteLine("File uninstalled");
}

Comment: I modified my code to try for three times. Try it. In your code we can't make make the method to return  bool, becuase total method needs to be modified

Comment: yes but even though the file does not exists it's retrying for 3 times . But my requirement is if the file exists then i need to retry for 3 times :(

Comment: Just change the condition blocks to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Hi Raj Kumar , When i try to execute my code window is not retrying with the above code if the file exists :( It's only executing once